# MySQL - Average values of data for every 3 hours?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have two tables in mysql that are collecting data. One collects every 3 hours and the other every 15 minutes. I am trying to create a forecast using this data using machine learning techniques which requires the data to be of the same time interval.

My question is, how can I get the average value for every 3 hours from both tables into a new table that organises them by date and hour? So of a format like:

Date   /  Hour    /  Table 1 3-hour average   /  Table 2 3-hour average

Table 1 (every 3 hours):
datetime(timestamp)/level(double)

Table 2 (every 15 minutes):
datetime(timestamp)/value(double)

I have managed to create a table that gives me the average per day, but I'd prefer something more accurate!

This is the statement I've already got for daily averages:

```
SELECT DAY(`datetime`),
AVG(`level`) AS `Table 1 Average` ,
(SELECT AVG(`value`) AS `Table 2 Daily Average` 
FROM `table2` 
WHERE DAY(`datetime`) = DAY(table1.datetime)
GROUP BY DAY(`datetime`))
FROM `table1` GROUP BY DAY(`datetime`);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You really just need to change the subquery.  I think this may do way you want:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       SELECT AVG(t2.`value`) 
        FROM `table2` 
        WHERE t2.datetime <= t1.datime and
              t2.datetime >= date_sub(t1.datetime, interval 3 hour)
       ) as t2_moving_average
FROM `table1` t1;
```

Comment: Sorry if I'm being stupid - this query just gave me the same value for every 3 hours?

Comment: I find that surprising.  This should be taking the time frame relative to each record in `table1`.